# linux-image-4.15.0-36* reduces the speed of rsync over ssh to 10 times less

Tags: kernel, ssh, rsync

With kernel version 4.15.0.36, the speed of rsync over ssh gets reduced to around 10 times less than with 4.15.0.34.

Is this a regression? On 4.15.34, everything works as expected.

If I go back to 4.15.0.34-generic, rsync over ssh receives data as fast as it can be sent. (120Mbits to 150Mbits), but on 4.15.0.36-generic rsync over ssh receives at about 10 times less.

Has anyone else noticed this? I fixed it by removing 4.15.0.36, and using 4.15.0.34.

Comment: The question may be marked off topic, but I was having a hard time finding report of this issue (or if anyone else was even experiencing it). This question was more discoverable in Google than launchpad. Van's answer gets us to the right place.

Answer (score 3):

We had a similar issue with our MySQL server farm (seven dedicated MySQL servers). Replication was very slow, falling behind for no apparent reason. We were reaching 24 hours of lag! We never had that kind of lag before. A couple of minutes at the most.

Long story short, we rebooted to 4.15.0.34 and the servers caught up replication with in minutes!

References:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1796895
- https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?26,669517